# Why would China hold joint drills with Russia during Covid?

Tags: russian-federation, china, covid-19

[Russia to join military drill in China, 'displays mutual trust, eyes Central Asian security'](https://www.globaltimes.cn/page/202107/1230026.shtml)

Given that Russia is currently experiencing 20k+ Covid cases a day while China is getting ~100/day, why would China agree to hold military drills with Russia right now? It sounds as though they are endangering their hard-won Covid record by mingling with the Russians.

I'm looking for an answer that explains how the Chinese know the participating Russians don't have Covid, e.g. do soldiers on both sides go through quarantine? If so how can one tell if the other country is conducting a rigorous quarantine?

**Edit**: from a [news article today](https://www.usnews.com/news/business/articles/2021-08-05/delta-variant-challenges-chinas-costly-lockdown-strategy) about the current Covid outbreak in China, illustrating the danger:

> The year's biggest outbreak has tentatively been traced to airport employees who cleaned a Russian airliner on July 10 in Nanjing, northwest of Shanghai in Jiangsu province, according to health officials.

Comment: Any answer would be just speculation.

Comment: @FluidCode how do you know it would be speculation? How would you prove a non-speculative answer does not exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as Russian army personnel is [vaccinated](https://tass.com/defense/1276643), danger is lower, than expected.

Of course, any people crowding during COVID is potentially dangerous - but it rarely becomes reason to stop military training - both on East and the West.

Answer (score 4):

Just a few ideas:

- You are dealing with soldiers. You do not need to convince them to quarentine afterwards, you just order them to.
- Similarly, you may keep them isolated a week in advance and then test them before the exercise.
- Also, you may make sure that they are vaccinated.
- Most of them will be younger and less affected.
- Most of the info that I have seen about those exercises do not involve big number of soldiers from different units and countries physically mixing up; each unit will act on its own and the issue is coordination (e.g. ensuring that the Chinese artillery does its firing exercise before the Russian infantery moves in). Probably at higher echelons there will be some need of interactions, but those will be less and perhaps they can do over the wire.

Answer (score 2):

Both countries are currently having a bit of a bromance, mostly because they are aligning themselves against the US/Western countries.  It makes sense for them to hold joint military exercises, this is a common practice to signal alliances.

Also, Russia sees benefits in exporting its military hardware to a customer that can handily pay for it (unlike, say, Syria).  China on the other hand needs to acquire weapon manufacturing knowhow, Russia is an excellent source and holding maneuvers together is a good seller/buyer type of event here.

Both countries take great pride in promoting their vaccine technology.  As stated in other answers, more constraints on military personnel can easily put in place wrt to controlling covid:  age, vaccination status, isolation protocols.

Joint exercises can also be done with a fair bit of distancing:  conventional war units do not typically have to mingle all that much in drills or combat, especially when there are language barriers.  Most of this would be done via *remote* command, communication and control hardware anyway.  Compared to normal *national* military operations, like cramming sailors together on a ship or submarine, the risks don't have to be particularly high.

Both countries' governments have strongly trumpeted their competence in controlling Covid, especially when contrasted with Western countries that have supposedly not done so well.

Since they do have reasons to hold military exercises and since they both have reasons to signal that Covid is "not a problem" for themselves, why not hold these drills?